# Combine two lists which have the same item in dict

Tags: python

I have two lists named `a_list` and `b_list`:

```
a_list = [{'category_id': 1, 'category_name': u'AAA'}, \
    { 'category_id': 2, 'category_name': u'BBB'}]

b_list = [{'project_count': u'20', 'category_name': u'AAA'}, \
    {'project_count': u'31', 'category_name': u'BBB'}]
```

I want to make a new list, `c_list`, which combines the `a_list` and `b_list` with `category_name`. The resulting list should look like:

```
c_list = [{'category_id': 1,'project_count': u'20', 'category_name': u'AAA'},\
    {'category_id': 2,'project_count': u'31', 'category_name': u'BBB'}]
```

The goal is to be able to access both the `page_max` and the 'category_id' for the same 'category_name'.

```
for entry in c_list:
    page_num =1
    category_name   =  entry['category_name']
    category_id     =  entry['category_id']
    url = 'https://www.test.com?category_id=%(category_id)s&page=%(page)s' % {'category_id': category_id, 'page': str(page_num)}
    print url

    # AAA project_count is 20 
    # BBB project_count is 31
    page_max = int(entry['project_count'])
    for i in range(page_max - 1):
        page_num += 1
        url = 'https://www.test.com?category_id=%(category_id)s&page=%(page)s' % {'category_id': category_id, 'page': str(page_num)}
        print url
```

How can I merge the dictionaries within the lists based on the value of the key `'category_name'`?

Comment: Are the lists always sorted according to `category_name` ?

Comment: How did `project_count` become 3 and 6?

Comment: sorry,3 and 6 is my test. I modify it

Comment: If possible combine two lists to form a dictionary with "category_id" as key. I believe this would be a better data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an intermediate dictionary of {category_name: dict} and then use update:

```
temp = {a['category_name']: dict(a) for a in a_list}
for b in b_list:
    temp[b['category_name']].update(b)
c_list = list(temp.values())    # list() unnecessary in py2.X
```

But this isn't guaranteed to preserve the order of the lists. If order is important:

```
c_list = [temp[a['category_name']] for a in a_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to you to preserve the order of the lists, you can use an ordered dictionary for the intermediate result.

Note that this solution also works if `a_list` and `b_list` do not perfectly overlap (one contains categories not found in the other).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Create a temporary dictionary and fill it with elements of a_list
# according to their keys. If order is not important, this can just be
# a dictionary comprehension
temp = OrderedDict()
for d in a_list:
    # dict(d) is used to make a copy of the original dictionary from a_list
    # if we just used 'd' directly, then the update below would also affect
    # the dictionary in a_list (because they would share a reference)
    temp[d['category_name']] = dict(d)

for b in b_list:
    # update each dictionary in temp with the values from the dictionaries
    # in b_list. Use 'setdefault' to either get or insert a dictionary at
    # the correct key (this allows a_list and b_list to have 
    # non-overlapping categories
    a = temp.setdefault(b['category_name'], {})
    a.update(b)

c_list = list(temp.values())
```

Comment: `temp[d['category_name'] = d]` do you have your `]` in the wrong place? And doesn't this also mutate the dictionaries in `a_list`, probably need `temp[d['category_name']] = dict(d)`

Comment: @achampion Right, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important, you can use this:

first copy `a_list` to `c_list`:

```
import copy
c_list=copy.deepcopy(a_list)

for i in c_list:
    for j in b_list:
        if i['category_name'] == j['category_name']:
            i['project_count'] = j['category_name']

print c_list
```

Output:

```
[{'project_count': u'AAA', 'category_id': 1, 'category_name': u'AAA'}, {'project_count': u'BBB', 'category_id': 2, 'category_name': u'BBB'}]
```